# MySQL Select Row With Highest Column Value

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Given the data set for a table `person_investments`:

| id | person | stock | invested |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | GOOG | 1000 |
| 2 | Jack | META | 800 |
| 3 | Jack | TSLA | 1500 |
| 4 | Jill | GOOG | 4000 |
| 5 | Jill | TSLA | 1000 |
| 6 | Taylor | WMT | 1000 |
| 7 | Taylor | TGT | 2500 |
| 8 | Taylor | HD | 1000 |

I'm trying to figure out how to query and get the stock in which each person is most invested. In this example, I'm looking for this result:

| id | person | stock | invested |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Jack | TSLA | 1500 |
| 4 | Jill | GOOG | 4000 |
| 7 | Taylor | TGT | 2500 |

I've been trying to work with something basic like this:

```
SELECT id, person, stock, MAX(invested) 
FROM person_investments
GROUP BY person;
```

However, with a real data set, I'm not getting the expected results. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to pick max in each group of person.
One was can be using `rank` -

```
select id, person,stock,invested
from (
 select id, person,stock,invested, 
 dense_rank() over (partition by person order by invested desc) rnk 
 from stock)s
where s.rnk =1;
```

Refer fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w29Xfku3P44dceL7d1EnBC/0).

I've also added a scenario where there are more then 1 max.

Comment: This worked, thank you! One minor edit, the name of the table was `person_investments` and not `stock`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, person, stock, MAX(invested) FROM person_investments GROUP BY stock,person;
```

In groupby field, you have to combine person and stock also.

Comment: This will not work, as ID is missing from ```group by```. Adding ID as well, will not give desired results